# Finding the absolute extrema of $F(x) = 2x + 5\cos(x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, extreme-value-theorem

> Find the absolute extrema of $F(x) = 2x + 5\cos(x)$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$ using the extreme value theorem.
>
> Answer should be 2 ordered pairs.

I got $\arcsin(2/5)$ for the first value of $x$, but can’t figure out the second.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the solutions of $2-5\sin(x)=0$ ?

Comment: I know one is arcsin(2/5) but I’m pretty sure there’s an additional answer within the given interval that I am having a hard time figuring out how to find. If you could help me find/tell me how to get the other solution I’d really appreciate it.

Comment: $\arcsin(\frac25)$ is a local max, but not the absolute max. You need to also test the endpoints of the interval. You are missing the minimum, and for that I would point out that $\sin(x)=\frac 25$ has other solutions on the given interval besides $\arcsin(\frac25)$. Hope these hints help you out.

Comment: Sorry I should have included that I tested the 3 points I have (0,arcsin(2/5), and 2pi) and got that 2pi is the absolute maximum. I just don’t know what the 4th solution on the interval is, I can’t figure it out and I’ve been working on it for some time. It’s all I’m missing to bring everything together, if you could tell me what the other solution is besides arcsin(2/5) I’d really appreciate it!

Comment: I see that the point is at x=2.73 from graphing it but I’m not sure how to get this point through a calculus method.

Comment: "I got arcsin(2/5) for the first value of x, but can’t figure out the second."  Remember there are four quadrants.  $\sin|\cos x = \pm k$ for any $0 < k < 1$ will occur exact once in each quadrant.  so $\sin x = \frac 25$ will have an $x$ in the first quadrant and in the second.  If $x =\arcsin \frac 25$ is in the first then $\pi-\arcsin \frac 25$ will occur in the second. (And $\sin x = -\frac 25$ will have solutions in the third and fourth at $x=\pi +\arcsin \frac 25$ and $x = -\arcsin \frac 25$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the fact that $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$ for all $x$.

You found the value $x=\arcsin(\frac25)\approx0.412$. As I mentioned in my comment above, that is a local maximum, and you also need to know about the endpoints of the interval before you can say if it is the absolute max. In this case, we have $F(\arcsin(\frac 25))<F(2\pi)$. The absolute max for the interval is $(2\pi,4\pi+5)$.

From what I said above above, another solution to the equation $\sin(x)=\frac25$ would be $x=\pi-0.412\approx2.73$, and that $x$ value is in the interval $[0,2\pi]$.

The ordered pair for that point, which is the absolute minimum, is approximately $(2.73,0.878)$.

I'd also point out that $\sin(x)=\sin(n\cdot\pi-x)$ for any odd integer value of $n$. You would need this information if you needed to find more extrema on a wider interval.

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was missing, thank you so much

Comment: Those are the *local* extrema.  Not the *absolute* extrema.

Comment: @fleablood isn't it correct to say that they are absolute extrema since the question restricts our attention to a specific interval?

Comment: Not if the endpoints have greater or less value.  Note at $x=2\pi$ the value is larger than then local maximum..... I'm perplexed as you yourself made that exact same comment.

Comment: Right, if you read my comment on the original question I pointed out the same thing. I never said that $\arcsin(\frac 25)$ is the absolute maximum. I can see why you might have thought that, though. I will edit my answer for clarity.

Comment: Okay, I reread and see you are addressing the OPs question of finding the fourth point.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=2x+5\cos x , x \in [0,2\pi], f'(x)=2-5 \sin x, f''(x)=-5 \cos x$
$$f'(x)=0 \implies \sin x=\frac{2}{5} \implies x_1= \sin^{-1} (2/5), x_2=\pi-\sin^{-1} (2/5)$$
$$f''(x_1)<0, f''(x_2)>0 \implies f_{max}=f(\sin^{-1}(2/5))=2\sin^{-1}(2/5)+\sqrt{21},$$ $$ f_{min}
=f(x_2)=2[\pi-\sin^{-1}(2/5)]-\sqrt{21}$$
$$f(0)=5, f[2\pi]=4\pi+5$$
So the absolute max is $f(2\pi)=4\pi+5$ and absolute min is $2[\pi-\sin^{-1}(2/5)]-\sqrt{21}$

Answer (score 1):

Derivative vanishes at $\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2}{5}$

plugin and extreme values are

$$ \sqrt{21} + 2(\sin^{-1}\dfrac{2}{5}+ 2 n \pi) $$

Odd multiples are discarded as they give a minimum, can be checked by sign of second derivative. Only alternate roots are considered for maxima.

and the corresponding x-values (first x- value of pair) are

$$ \sin^{-1}(2/5) + 2 n \pi $$

Answer (score 1):

The question says *absolute* extreme.

$5\cos x \le 5$ and $2x \le 4\pi$ so $2x+ 5\cos x\le 5+4\pi$ so if $2x + 5\cos x$ ever equals $5+4\pi$, which it does at $x = 2\pi$, that will be an absolute (albeit not necessarily a local) maximum.  So the absolute maximum is $(2\pi, 5+4\pi)$.

We can't do the same for minimum as $2x \ge 0$ and $5\cos x \ge -5$ but when $2x=0$ we do not have $5\cos x =-5$ for $x =0$ so $2x + 5\cos x > -5$.

For a minimum we can find local minimum via $[2x+5\cos x]'= 2 -5\sin x = 0$ so $\sin x =\frac 25$.  So $0<\frac 25 < 1$ there will be one such value $x_1$ in the first quadrant and a second value $x_2$ in the second quadrant.  $x_1$ is $\arcsin \frac 25$ and $x_2$ is $\pi-\arcsin \frac 25$.

As $\sin x_1 =\frac 25$ then $\cos x_1 = \sqrt{1 - \frac 4{25}} = \frac {\sqrt{21}}5$.  And $x_2$ being in the second quadrant has $\cos x_2 = -\frac {\sqrt {21}}5$.

So the local extrema are $(\arcsin \frac 25, 2\arcsin \frac 25 + \sqrt {21})$ and $(\pi - \arcsin \frac 25, 2\pi - 2\arcsin \frac 25-\sqrt{21})$

Now $\frac 25 < \frac 12$ so $0< \arcsin \frac 25 < \frac \pi 6$  and $5>\sqrt{21} > 4$ so $2\pi -2\arcsin \frac 25-\sqrt{21} < 2\pi - 4 < 7- 4 =3< \sqrt{21}<2\arcsin \frac 25 + \sqrt {21}< 4\pi + 5$

So $(\pi - \arcsin \frac 25, 2\pi - 2\arcsin \frac 25-\sqrt{21})$ is a local minimum and $(\arcsin \frac 25, 2\arcsin \frac 25 + \sqrt {21})$ is a local but *NOT* an absolute maximum.

Now $2*0 + 5\cos 0  =5> 3 >2\pi -2\arcsin \frac 25-\sqrt{21}$.  So the local minimum *is* the absolute minimum.

So the absolute extrema at the local minimum, $(\pi - \arcsin \frac 25, 2\pi - 2\arcsin \frac 25-\sqrt{21})$ and at the end point, $(2\pi, 4\pi + 5)$.

Answer (score 1):

The possible locations for the extreme values of $f(x)=2x+5\cos x$ on $[0,2\pi]$ are at the endpoints $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$ and the critical points, where $f'(x)=2-5\sin x=0$, which is to say at $x=\arcsin(2/5)\approx0.4115$ and $x=\pi-\arcsin(2/5)\approx2.73$. To determine where the absolute maximum and absolute minimum occur, it suffices to evaluate the function at all four points and see what we get:

$$\begin{align}
f(0)&=2\cdot0+5\cos0=5\\
f(\arcsin(2/5))&=2\arcsin(2/5)+5\cos(\arcsin(2/5))\\
&\approx0.823+5\sqrt{1-(2/5)^2}\\
&=0.823+\sqrt{21}\\
&\approx5.406\\
f(\pi-\arcsin(2/5))&=2\pi-2\arcsin(2/5))+5\cos(\pi-\arcsin(2/5))\\
&\approx6.283-.823-5\cos(\arcsin(2/5))\\
&=5.46-\sqrt{21}\\
&\approx0.877\\
f(2\pi)&=2\cdot2\pi+5\cos(2\pi)=4\pi+5\approx17.566\\
\end{align}$$

So the absolute maximum occurs at $x=2\pi$, and the absolute minimum occurs at $x=\pi-\arcsin(2/5)$.

Remark: With a bit of thought, it's unnecessary to explicitly evaluate the function at the four points in order to see where the extrema occur. Since $|\cos x|\le1$ for all $x$, it's clear that $f(x)\le2x+5$, so the absolute maximum necessarily occurs at $x=2\pi$.  And since $f''(x)=-5\cos x$ is negative at $x=\arcsin(2/5)$ and positive at $x=\pi-\arcsin(2/5)$, the function has a local maximum at the first critical point and a local minimum at the second. To see that that point is the absolute minimum, it suffices to check that $f(x)\lt f(0)=5$ for *some* point in $[0,2\pi]$. And $f(\pi/2)=\pi$ does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This function $f(x)= 2x+5\cos{x}$ on $[0,2\pi]$ has one stationary point at $\arcsin{\frac{2}{5}}$. Next you look at the boundary points. It turns out that $f$ has an absolute maximum at the boundary point $x=2\pi$. You should be able to work out the details.

Comment: So there is only 1 critical point between 0 and 2pi? I thought there would be two because when I graph it I see there’s an inflection point at arcsin(2/5) and then one at around x=2.73.